# how do i inject css in gwt?

Tags: html, css, gwt

how do i inject css into gwt without actually having to use  into the gwt.xml file ?
i have a module in another package and css in another package 
now i need to include those css to Widgets. how do i do that ?
i  dont want to define those css styles in main style sheet which is in war directory

say i have a widget someWidget and style ".someWidget:HOVER{}"
how do i apply that css, 
its easier to just apply css to the widget using addStyleName or so ,
but without using public how to inject CSS to the HTML ?

*i have a package com.someWidget which has widgets , and have package com.Styles.css which has all the styles. and i have a client bundle for those css in to com.Style*

Comment: Is the CSS in a package that resides on the client side of the application? Please be more specific about the package structure you've employed.

Comment: alright sir,details added, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an interface `Styles` that extends [`CssResource`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.html) then injecting the styles into the page is simple:

```
// myCss is a concrete implementation of the Styles interface
myCss.ensureInjected();
```